# Which grant type should be used for the on behalf of token in Azure?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am having some 3 different application which is hosted in Azure. For example, Spa, Graph and API application. I am having the user token for the Graph Application from Spa. Now, I need to access the API Application using graph access token. I am trying to get the API Application Access token using middle ware application. But unfortunately, I am getting an error for the requested grant type(unsupported_grant_type error in response).

**End Point:** oauth2/token

**Request:**

```
grant_type:urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer.
client_id :<<Client ID>>
client_secret : <client_secret>>
resource  : <<app URI>>
requested_token_use : <<on_behalf_of>>
scope : openid
assertion : <<Graph App Token>>
```

**Note:** I have used spa to graph user token as assertion. Please suggest a valid grant type.

**Response:** (400 Bad request)

```
{
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
    "error_description": "AADSTS70003: The access grant 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer.' is not supported.\r\nTrace ID: 6534870f-662d-4543-acbc-250b89a00700\r\nCorrelation ID: 4ea54718-94ee-4151-abe9-4fca5469c7c5\r\nTimestamp: 2018-05-17 03:53:57Z",
    "error_codes": [
        70003
    ],
    "timestamp": "2018-05-17 03:53:57Z",
    "trace_id": "6534870f-662d-4543-acbc-250b89a00700",
    "correlation_id": "4ea54718-94ee-4151-abe9-4fca5469c7c5"
}
```

Comment: Could you add the error here? Though I'm gonna make a guess and say it is the one about an implicit grant token being unable to "elevate" to a confidential client token.

Comment: Hi Juunas, I have updated the actual response in the question section. Please check it

Comment: Hmm, well the error is different. Is your app of type Native or Web app/API in Azure AD?

Comment: It is a web app/API in Azure AD

Comment: The only thing that sounds like it could be the reason for this is the "Graph app token". You have to give the token that your API got as authentication, and the resource should be the identifier of the API you want the on-behalf-of token for.

Comment: Sorry junnas. I am not getting the point "You have to give the token that your API got as authentication".  Whether Graph to API token needs to be given by mentioning the resource as API URI?

Comment: Explaining the flow and the usage of the parameters would take a bit too much time. You can check out my article on the flow: https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-on-behalf-of-aspnet-core

Comment: Thanks Juunas!!! I will check the above article.

Comment: @Junnas, I have changed the request type as below and getting the response.  resource : <<Resource name>>,
client_id : "<<Client id of app>>",
client_secret :"<<Client secret of app>>",
grant_type : client_credentials,
assertion  : urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer,
requested_token_use : on_behalf_of,
scope : openid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the above problem with the  small corrections and I am getting the access token as expected. changed the request as below (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of)

```
grant_type      : urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
client_id       : << Middle App Client ID >>
client_secret   : << Middle App Client Secret >>
assertion       : <<Access Token of middle App from SPA>>
requested_token_use : on_behalf_of
scope           : openid
resource        : << Actual Resource Name which requires access token >>
```